# nav-tab issue in bootstrap across different browsers

Tags: nav

I am currently having an issue with the nav-tab in bootstrap.  I have set up the CSS so that the active tab is a green color.  When it is hovered, it turns into a brown color.  When a user were to click on a different tab, the new active tab would turn the original green color.
The issue that I am having is that in Chrome, it works perfectly.  However, in IE and Firefox, after the user clicks on a tab, it stays the brown color and never reverts to the green color like it is supposed to.  It only reverts back when I click anywhere on the screen.  Any help would certainly be appreciated.

```
.nav-tabs {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.nav-tabs:before,
.nav-tabs:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.nav-tabs:after {
  clear: both;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #613821;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
          border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
  background-image:url(../img/navwoodback.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  /*background-color: #ffffff;*/
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-tabs > .active > a,
.nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #3b4223;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```